# Fill in gaps in a repeated sequence in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores questions 1 - 16 and their answers given by users, and grouped by their unique id. For example:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| number | question_number | answer |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| 1      | 1               | y      |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| 1      | 2               | n      |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| 1      | 3               | y      |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| 2      | 1               | n      |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| 2      | 3               | y      |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

What I want is a SELECT or an INSERT where it will fill the missing values in the sequence. So in the case on 'number' 2, it will fill in question_number 2 and insert a null value for answer. So essentially I want to fill in the gaps for the repeated sequence (in my example's case, 1-3)

Comment: so you are presented 1:1 1:2 1:3 2:1 2:3 as rows, and from that you deduce you are missing 2:2 null ?

Comment: I think you will either need a table which has the full sequence of questions or you will need some dynamic SQL.

Comment: And if you presented 1:1 1:9 2:1 thru 2:8 and 3:1 you would deduced you are missing 1:2 thru 1:8, 2:9 and 3:2 thru 3:9 or some other unspoken VOODOO ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and I want to fill in those rows through sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select n.number, qn.question_number, q.answer
from (select distinct number from questions) n cross join
     (select distinct question_number from questions) qn left join
     questions q
     on q.number = n.number and q.question_number = qn.question_number;
```

Comment: So I join with the same table?

Comment: @KristinVernon . . . The `cross join` is to generate all the combinations for the `number` and `question_number`.  The valid values are coming from the  original table, so yes, this is a self-join.